# How to pass multiple variables for a multi select in a request

Tags: servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

Basically I have a request that accepts multiple values and I want to send multiple via the API for now using rest api explorer.  The Software is a multiselect as shown.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The fix for this ended up being turning the software request into an array by changing it to the following:

```
"software": [ "item1", "item2" ]
```